# How can i edit OSGi bundles manifest file in Netbeans 6.9?

Tags: java, netbeans, osgi

I'm using Netbeans 6.9 RC2 and Maven OSGi Bundle project template. Actually i dont want to test my bundles in Netbeans environment so i copy the jar file to the OSGi container directory and install it from command line. But when i want to see its headers from OSGi console, i see a lot of Netbeans related unnecessary stuff. Is it possible to edit the contents of the manifest file in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Netbeans does not allow to edit manifest file, no matter what i do it just adds the unedited version of file. Answered my own question for people who has similar problems.